# Compiling MongoDB C++ Driver, Boost Error (Windows)

Tags: mongodb, boost

I am trying to compile the MongoDB C++ Driver on Windows. I am using the SCons "Make" Tool. and it is giving me a Boost Error, I have boot libraries but I am unsure how to get it to link with the SCons Build file. I am use to just adding the reference in VS. It looks like i need an environment variable reference but I am not sure.

here is the Error:

```
scons mongoclient
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C++ library boost_thread-mt... (cached) no
Checking for C++ library boost_thread... (cached) no
Checking for C++ library boost_filesystem-mt... (cached) no
Checking for C++ library boost_filesystem... (cached) no
Checking for C++ library boost_system-mt... (cached) no
Checking for C++ library boost_system... (cached) no
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
cl /Fobuild\mongo\bson\oid.obj /c src\mongo\bson\oid.cpp /TP /nologo /EHsc /O2 /
D_SCONS /DMONGO_EXPOSE_MACROS /Ibuild /Isrc /Ibuild\mongo /Isrc\mongo
oid.cpp
src\mongo/pch.h(48) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/shared
_ptr.hpp': No such file or directory
scons: *** [build\mongo\bson\oid.obj] Error 2
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

in the SConstruct file I find the following but not sure what exactly means for finding the boost libraries.

```
boostLibs = ["thread", "filesystem", "system"]
conf = Configure(env)
for lib in boostLibs:
    if not conf.CheckLib(["boost_%s-mt" % lib, "boost_%s" % lib],
                         language="C++"):
        if not win:
            Exit(1)
conf.Finish()
```

Comment: Since you're having trouble with the C++ install, can I assume you had no problems with the C driver build? Because that's where I'm stuck right now. On mongodb-dot-org `C++ MongoDB Driver` page it says download the C++ driver, then go to this link to install it:  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Quickstart-Guide-(New-Driver) The first thing that page tells you to do is install the **C driver** (which also builds libbson, if needed). *Then* it instructs to compile the C++ driver. Am I reading it wrong? Is it a single page for both installs, & I'm only supposed to do the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was finally able to the boost Libs to show up by finding this:

```
scons --extrapath=c:\boost
```

the C:\boost being the directory for boost. I am now experiencing compiler errors but that is further than before.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional include path using the --cpppath option

```
--cpppath : Include path if you have headers in a nonstandard directory
```

Moreover remember to compile your boot library and to link to the correct folder containing the boost library .lib files

```
--libpath : Library path if you have libraries in a nonstandard directory
```

Thus you should issue a command similar to:

```
scons --cpppath=c:\boost --libpath=c:\boost\stage\lib
```